# In fluid, how do I use a widget only if it exists?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I am making a sitepackage to be compatible with TYPO3 9 & 10. However it is using the news extension which changes the way pagination is done.

Is there a way in fluid to do something like:

```
<f:if condition="n:widget.paginate">
  <f:then>
    Use n:widget.paginate
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    Use newer paginate method
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is no such condition.

You might define a view helper to check the installation of an extension and the extension version. Or you use a view helper to check the existence of a class representing the view helper.

In [`ext:vhs`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/vhs) you find a view helper to [check if an extension is loaded](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Extension/Loaded.html) and a [`try` view helper](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Try.html) to catch a rendering error.

Comment: Alternatively, can I check the news version, and/or typo3 version, and do it that way?

Comment: that might be a possible condition at the moment, but long time you do not know whether the needed class will exist in `ext:news` for any later version of `ext:news` or `TYPO3`